# как выйти из бесконечного асинхронного цикла node.js

Tags: node.js, асинхронность, event-loop

У меня есть БД с неизвестным числом строк. Строки имеют идентификатор от 1 до бесконечности.
Задача - максимально быстро получить всё строки.

```
function dbWork(){
for(let i=1; true; i++){
        db.get({id:i}, someAction);
    }
}

function someAction(data){
    if (data.value) {...};
    else // завершаем dbWork(), который до сих пор крутится бесконечно
}
```

Понятное дело, что несколько тысяч запросов могут улететь на несуществующие индексы. Но это не столь важно.
Очень нужно понять, как выйти из бесконечного асинхронного цикла.
Все решения, которые я находил, подразумевают, что я знаю сколько должен сделать запросов. Но загвоздка в том, что я не знаю.
Таблица может быть как с 1-ой строкой, так и с миллиардом.

Comment: может в начале цикла пробовать добавить условие?

Comment: может рекурсия?

Comment: вроде как, выход из цикла - `break`, только нужно условие прописать

Comment: break не подойдёт.
не в этом случае.
цикл нужно завершить из коллбека